# Set padding of toolbar on AppCompactActivity

Tags: android-layout

how to set padding of toolbar android like this?

This is example of toolbar i want to costumize in my application

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGn6C.png

I have tried to set padding from style in values folder by adding item android:padding but dosent work.
Does anybody know the exact solution for my problem?

Thank you, i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this tutorial link. 

 
https://sourcey.com/android-custom-centered-actionbar-with-material-design/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- This is a centered logo -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <!-- This is a centered title -->
        <!--
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
            />
            -->

        <!-- This is a custom left side button -->
        <!--
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton" />
            -->

        <!-- This is a custom right side button -->
        <!--
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_search"
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_magnify_white_24dp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton" />
            -->

    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

If you read full tutorial then you can easily modify your custom toolbar. Best of luck!